# JSONP Object Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to make a cross domain request to send/recieve some data. I can't get past the `object error`. Before I was getting the `No Transport` Error but adding `Query.support.cors = true;` solved this issue.

```
var url = "http://CROSSDOMAINSERVER:PORT/Service1.svc/GetDataUsingDataContract";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: 'tool=1&product=Some%20Product&details=9&bogus=should%20not%20pass%20validation', 
                datatype: "jsonp",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.statusText);
                }
            });
```

If I type the url out in a browser:

```
 http://CROSSDOMAINSERVER:PORT/Service1.svc/GetDataUsingDataContract?&tool=1&product=Some%20Product&details=9&bogus=should%20not%20pass%20validation
```

I get the correct response.

```
{"d":{"__type":"ClientSideData:#ProdResourceToolService","details":"9","product":"Some Product","result":"1","site":"Somewhere, SD","systime":"2\/6\/2013 2:50:20 PM","team":"0000000000","tool":"1","user":"username"}}
```

When I use ajax it does not submit it to the database or return data, just `object error`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this?

I should also specify if I remove `http://CROSSDOMAINSERVER:PORT/` from `var url` when debugging locally I get the correct json response. Why does cross domain not work?

Comment: That response is not correct if you really want to do JSONP.  The return value from JSONP is supposed to be JavaScript code for a function call, not just plain JSON.

Comment: From the last line of the question, it looks like you're running this from the same domain! Are you running this from `http://localhost/`?

Comment: jsonp is the only way to do a cross domain request though right?

Comment: Where did you get the idea of changing `$.support.cors` to `true`?  If a browser doesn't support cors, making it use cors won't make it any better.

Comment: Also note, IE < 10 does not fully support CORS (requires a different XHR that jQuery doesn't implement).

Comment: If you are doing JSONP, you don't need CORS. If you are doing CORS, you don't need JSONP. using them together is just confusing.

Comment: @KevinB You might be on to something. The browser I'm testing with is IE7

Comment: @atrueresistance All browsers support JSONP. If the webservice you are accessing offers JSONP, you should use it. Note, JSON != JSONP.

Answer (score 3):

This is your current response:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__type": "ClientSideData:#ProdResourceToolService",
        "details": "9",
        "product": "Some Product",
        "result": "1",
        "site": "Somewhere, SD",
        "systime": "2/6/2013 2:50:20 PM",
        "team": "0000000000",
        "tool": "1",
        "user": "username"
    }
}
```

This is a valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string. However, its not valid [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). If possible, make your service wrap the json in a function:

```
responseFunc({
    "d": {
        "__type": "ClientSideData:#ProdResourceToolService",
        "details": "9",
        "product": "Some Product",
        "result": "1",
        "site": "Somewhere, SD",
        "systime": "2/6/2013 2:50:20 PM",
        "team": "0000000000",
        "tool": "1",
        "user": "username"
    }
});
```

And in your `$.ajax()` call, add a property: `jsonpCallback: 'responseFunc'`.

Also, I would suggest passing the `data` as an object:

```
data: { tool: 1, product: 'Some Product' } //etc...
```

If you can access the service from the serverside without any issues you could create a httphandler (.ashx for example) and let it generate the JSON for you. Then you wouldn't have to deal with the cross domain issues on the client side.